# Access Context & SurfaceView from ViewModel

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I'm having trouble complying with the MVVM with Jetpack Compose, because my ViewModel needs to access a view.

I need to stream a camera source onto a `SurfaceView`. However, this source has an independant lifecycle : it can be plugged in or removed anytime, while the view is visible or not.

To start streaming, I need to provide the SurfaceView to an external SDK. How can I do that without breaking the MVVVM?
I want to start streaming :

- whenever the view appears (first composition), if the source is available
- whenever the source becomes available, if the view is visible

What I've done so far is to inject the SurfaceView into the ViewModel

```kotlin
class CameraVM: ViewModel() {
  lateinit var surfaceView: SurfaceView

  init {
    listenForStreamSourceAvailability()
  }

  // Called when source becomes available
  fun startStreaming() {
    camera.setupStreaming(surfaceView)
    camera.startStreaming()
  }
```

And in `CameraView`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CameraView(viewModel: CameraVM = viewModel()) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val localSurfaceView: SurfaceView = remember {
        val surfaceView = SurfaceView(context)
        // Inject surface view only at first composition
        viewModel.surfaceView = surfaceView
        surfaceView
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            localSurfaceView
        }
    )
}
```

Maybe `DisposableEffect` could be useful ?